# sampling based on specified column values in R

Tags: r, random, dplyr, sample, sampling

I have a data like this, where Average is the average of X, Y, and Z.

```
head(df)
ID  X   Y   Z   Average
A   2   2   5   3
A   4   3   2   3
A   4   3   2   3
B   5   3   1   3
B   3   4   2   3
B   1   5   3   3
C   5   3   1   3
C   2   3   4   3
C   5   3   1   3
D   2   3   4   3
D   3   2   4   3
D   3   2   4   3
E   5   3   1   3
E   4   3   2   3
E   3   4   2   3
```

To reproduce this, we can use

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E"),
                     X = c(2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L,1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L),
                     Y = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), 
                     Z = c(5L, 2L, 2L,1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
                     Average = c(3L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L))
```

From this, I want to extract one observation per ID such that we don't get same (as much as is possible) values of the combination of X, Y, and Z. I tried

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% sample_n(size = nrow(.), replace = FALSE) %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = T)
```

But, on a larger dataset, I see too many repetitions of the combination of X, Y, Z. To the extent possible, I need the output with equal or close to equal representation of cases (i.e. the combination of X, Y, Y) like this:

```
   ID   X   Y   Z   Average
    A   2   2   5   3
    B   5   3   1   3
    C   2   3   4   3
    D   3   2   4   3
    E   4   3   2   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems dubious, but try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% add_count(X, Y, Z) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    top_n(-1, n) %>%
    arrange(runif(n)) %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    slice(1)
# # A tibble: 5 x 5
# # Groups:   ID [5]
#       ID     X     Y     Z Average
#   <fctr> <int> <int> <int>   <int>
# 1      A     2     2     5       3
# 2      B     1     5     3       3
# 3      C     2     3     4       3
# 4      D     3     2     4       3
# 5      E     3     4     2       3
```

This picks the least common XYZ combo from each ID, and in case of a tie chooses randomly. Extremely common XYZ combos may be missing entirely.

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way to get the combinations closer to the averages? Like if the average is 3, more weight should be given to x,y,z values of 2, 3, 4 and less to 1, 5, 3.

Comment: Well, you could add in a standard deviation column and use smaller standard deviation as a tie-breaker instead of my random choice. But this makes me even more skeptical of you process - you have so many conflicting wants - a "random" sample, favoring less-common combos, but also preferring combos that are closer to the average...

Comment: Sorry about that! I want to be able to pick combos that are closer to the average for more number of times, but I don't want a situation where 3 is made of a combo 3,3,3 for 100% of the times.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things and should just stick with a random sample by ID. Anything you get out of these pseudo-random methods will be skewed in ways that are difficult to understand.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(X, Y, Z) %>% mutate(n = n())` is `df %>% add_count(X,Y,Z)`, `group_by` overrides groups by default so no need for `ungroup`, `filter(n==min(n))` is `top_n(-1,n)`, and I'd also simplify your slice and arrange combination to get : `df %>% add_count(X,Y,Z) %>% group_by(ID) %>% top_n(-1,n) %>% slice(sample(n(),1)) %>% select(-n)`

Comment: Thanks, I haven't kept up at all with all the new single-purpose functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. Explanations inline. Note that the implementation can be tweaked depending on the desired notion of "similarity"/"duplication" between rows.

```
# get the sample data from the original post
dat <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A","A","A","B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E"),
  X = c(2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L,1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L),
  Y = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L),
  Z = c(5L, 2L, 2L,1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
  Average = c(3L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L))
```

Define a function that samples a row of a data frame given an id (assumes `$ID` column exists):

```
# function to get a randomly sampled row from `df` with `df$ID==id`
id_sample <- function(df, id){
  df <- df[df$ID==id, ]
  return(df[sample(1:nrow(df), size=1), ])
}
```

Define a function that will loop over each id, rejecting a sample if it is "too similar" to the rows already in the data frame:

```
make_sample_df <- function(dat, threshold){

  # initialize empty data frame to fill with row samples
  out <- dat[NULL, ]

  # get the unique id's to loop over
  ids <- unique(dat$ID)

  for (id in ids){

    # grab a sample
    id_row <- id_sample(dat, id)

    # see how many of its elements have column-duplicates (zero for first id)
    n_dupes <- sum(apply(out, 1, function(row){
      sum(row[1]==id_row$X, row[2]==id_row$Y, row[3]==id_row$Z)}))

    # keep getting samps if the number of duplicates is higher than threshold
    while (n_dupes > threshold){

      id_row <- id_sample(dat, id)

      n_dupes <- sum(apply(out, 1, function(row){
        sum(row[1]==id_row$X, row[2]==id_row$Y, row[3]==id_row$Z)}))
    }

    # once we have a suitable row for `id`, add it to the output df
    out <- rbind(out, id_row)
  }

  return(out)
}
```

Now apply the func to OP's data and inspect:

```
# rows at most 1 of whose values appear in another row (at same column)     
set.seed(6933)
make_sample_df(dat, threshold=1)

## ID X Y Z Average
## A  4 3 2       3
## B  1 5 3       3
## C  2 3 4       3
## D  3 2 4       3
## E  5 3 1       3
```

Depending on your needs, you can try different `threshold` values, though note that if you're too strict about `threshold`, the `while` loop could keep running forever, so you might want to put some kind of escape hatch in there.

You can also adapt this strategy to different variations, e.g. where you care about values getting duplicated within rows, instead of columns.

Hope this helps ~~

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way to get the combinations closer to the averages? Like if the average is 3, more weight should be given to x,y,z values of 2, 3, 4 and less to 1, 5, 3.

Comment: Yep for sure -- probably the best starting point will be the `prob` parameter of `sample()`. From the docs: "`prob` a vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled."

Comment: Given R's vectorization it will probably be faster to compute `n_dupes` for all rows of a particular ID at the same time and then sample from the rows with the fewest dupes. In your method, the algorithm can waste time picking the same sample multiple times, and if no rows are below the threshold it will be an infinite loop. At the very least, you could have `id_sample` return all the rows for an ID in a random order and then you iterate through them, rather than resampling.

Comment: yep those are all good points! the answer is a first pass at the problem. definitely not optimal performance-wise but illustrates the general idea. shuffling the rows first is def a better approach than just sampling them -- agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add to the answer from lefft. I modified the code to allow sample sizes and not dependent on having a column called ID, or X,Y,Z, or any of that

```
id_sample <- function(df, id, field, sampleSize) {
  df = df %>%
   filter(!!as.symbol(field) == id)
  return(df[sample(1:nrow(df), size = sampleSize, replace = TRUE),])
}

  make_sample_df <- function(dat, sampleSize, field) {
   # initialize empty data frame to fill with row samples
  out <- dat[NULL,]
  # get the unique id's to loop over
  ids <- unique(dat[[field]])
   for (id in ids) {
    # grab a sample
    id_row <- id_sample(dat, id, field,sampleSize)
   out <- rbind(out, id_row)
     }
  return(out)
  }
```

And then how I use this is

```
   sample_df = make_sample_df(df, 20, "ColumnToSampleOn")
```

where df is my original dataframe, 20 is the count of rows I want for each unique value found in the "ColumnToSampleOn"

Comment: Thanks Josh! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be by `excluding` values which has been sampled for previous column.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(XX = sample(unique(X),1),
            YY = sample(unique(Y[Y!=XX]),1),
            ZZ = sample(unique(Z[Z!=XX & Z!=YY]),1),
            Average = mean(Average))
# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#    ID        XX    YY    ZZ Average
#   <fctr> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
# 1 A          4     2     1    3.00
# 2 B          5     4     2    3.00
# 3 C          5     3     1    3.00
# 4 D          2     3     2    3.00
# 5 E          5     4     2    3.00
```

I have changed column names just make the logic clear.